# Merge dataframes with repeated keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe:

```
A | B | Key
1   a    1
2   b    2
3   c    2
4   d    1
```

and another one like :

```
Key  |  G
1     Gate1
2     Gate2
```

and I want to combine the first dataframe with the other dataframe such that it shows:

```
A  | B   |   Key  |  G
1    a        1     Gate1
2    b        2     Gate2
3    c        2     Gate2
4    d        1     Gate1
```

I have not been able to merge these two dataframes in a way that I am duplicating the rows of the second dataframe, and then merging to the first frame.

Comment: One way is to turn the second DataFrame into a Series whose index is the Key, then `.map()`: `df1['G'] = df1['Key'].map(df2.set_index('Key')['G'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do (I'll name dataframe one as df1 and this another one as df2):

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Key', how='left')
```